# date difference when two criteria is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to define how long a ticket has stayed in a specific task. I have the columns. My SQL looks like below.

```
select 
[number],
datestamp, 
assignment_group,
[sequence]
from #ranking1
order by [number],[sequence]
```

I am sure there is a easy way to do this though I am not quite sure what it is anymore. My data currently looks like:

```
ticket no   Datestamp   taskNo  ranking
IM123456    3/24/2016 13:44 task1   1
IM123456    3/24/2016 17:01 task2   2
IM123456    4/20/2016 11:57 task3   3
IM123456    5/26/2016 10:50 task3   4
IM123456    7/29/2016 15:39 task1   5
IM123456    8/2/2016 13:15  task2   6
IM123456    10/25/2016 15:42task1   7
IM123456    10/26/2016 16:27task2   8
IM321654    4/5/2016 11:53  task4   1
IM321654    4/8/2016 16:06  task1   2
IM321654    4/11/2016 13:33 task6   3
IM321654    5/12/2016 15:58 task1   4
```

What I want my end results to be is

```
Number  Task    Number_days
IM123456    task1   4
IM123456    task2   111
IM123456    task3   100
IM123456    task1   3
IM123456    task4   0
IM123456    task6   31
```

I hope I managed to make some sense. I'm using SQL studio 2016

Comment: Is your end result correct based on your sample data? For example, IM123456, task1, why the end result has Number_days of 4? It should have 215 to me between 3/24/2016 and 10/25/2016.

Comment: It is the difference between the next date and not the max date for each number. That is to say that it is the total time that number spent in task1

Comment: I get different numbers. E.g.: IM123456/task1: There are three entries: `2016-03-24`, `2016-07-29`, and `2016-10-25`. So the task was begun on `2016-03-24` and closed on `2016-07-29` = 127 days. Then it was begun again on `2016-10-25` and has not been closed again as yet. Or am I misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: @sophieDeslongchamps, I think it will be helpful if you can explain why IM123456/task1 has 4 days (based on your current sample data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LAG` to look into a previous record. So when you look at one `[number]` and task (`assignment_group`) and order its records by `datestamp`, you want every other record and subtract the previous `datestamp` from its own.

```
select
  [number],
  assignment_group,
  datediff(day, datebefore, datestamp) as number_days
from
(
  select 
    [number],
    datestamp, 
    assignment_group,
    row_number() over (partition by [number], assignment_group order by datestamp) as rn,
    lag(datestamp) over (partition by [number], assignment_group order by datestamp)
      as datebefore
  from #ranking1
) data
where rn % 2 = 0
order by [number], datestamp;
```

Or use `rn % 2 = 1` and `LEAD` to get the *next* `datestamp` instead. Then you would also show numbers that have an opening record, but no closing one, yet.

Tried here: http://rextester.com/JAT25484 and here: http://rextester.com/BEHBO43980.

Comment: I thought it was working but the number of days it's giving me doesn't seem to be adding up. I have number datestamp assignment_group sequence
IM1234 3/24/2016 task1 1
IM1234 3/24/2016 task2 2
IM1234 4/20/2016 task3 3
IM1234 5/26/2016 task3 4
IM1234 7/29/2016 task1 5
IM1234 8/2/2016 task2 6
IM1234 10/25/2016 task1 7
IM1234 10/26/2016 task2 8  what I should have is IM1234 task1 111
IM1234 task2 5
IM1234 task3 100

Comment: Oops, you are right, I missed the `assignment_group` in the partitions. Please check my updated query.

Comment: Now that it is almost working it is showing a flaw in my data tables that I have to ho back and fix. that being said I modified a few statements and it works perfectly! THANK YOU for your patience. ps the rextester was amazing at helping me figure what the lines I was not sure about.  sorry about the format can't seem to find the format in the comments in this forum. the code I ended up using (see next comment)

Comment: is select
  [number],
  assignment_group,
  datediff(day, datestamp, dateafter) as number_days
from
(
  select 
    [number],
    datestamp, 
    assignment_group,
    dense_rank() over (partition by [number] order by [number],datestamp) as rn,
    lead(datestamp) over (partition by [number] order by datestamp) as dateafter
  from #almost 
) data
order by [number], assignment_group, datestamp